# Pull in HTML resource in the background in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache, preload, image-preloader

On a page, there is a button. When the button is clicked, a dropdown shows up. The dropdown contains an image. The problem is that the image is not fetched until the user clicks the button.

```
$("#my_button").click(function(){
    $("#my_dropdown").html("<img src=\"http://mysite.com/image.jpg\" />"); 
});
```

I'd like to fetch the image when the page loads so it's ready to go when the user clicks the dropdown. How can I do this? I was thinking I could insert the image into the page with `display:none` set, so it'll get in the cache, or is there a way to load in when the document loads in jQuery?

This is for a Chrome extension, if it makes any difference. I suppose I could put the image in the extension (and that would be faster), but I'm still curious if it's possible to load the image using JS.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: I got my answer in first and it's essentially the same as what you accepted.  Just curious how you chose which answer to accept.

Comment: @Sparky672, he's probably just shy about using the awesomeness of inlining it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Just define it as a new image in the ready() call of the page:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
     var preload = new Image();
     preload.src = "http://mysite.com/image.jpg";
});
```

Then when you use it, it will already be in the browser's cache. You can use the variable or just reference it the same way you already are.

Comment: do you even need the ready() call? why not just run it at execution time?

Comment: @KevinBurke I can't think of any reason why not.

Answer (score 6):

You could preload each image...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (new Image()).src  =  '/path/to/myImage.jpg';
});
```