# Force Download an Image Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-io, force-download

I want to know if there is any way to make a script using Javascript/jQuery to download (open a download dialog) a image so the browser won't just show it.

Comment: I asked this a few weeks ago, see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473832/pull-in-html-resource-in-the-background-in-jquery

Comment: @Nathan: what server are you using? Apache, IIS?

Comment: Kevin Burke - the question you linked doesn't seem to have any overlap with this. Preloading images vs. forcing a download? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473832/pull-in-html-resource-in-the-background-in-jquery

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to use server-side scripting for this. [Search on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=force%20download%20script).

Alternately, your server might allow you to alter headers dynamically via configuration.

#### Apache solution with mod_headers

Place your downloadable images in a directory. Inside this directory, create a `.htaccess` file with the following contents:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "([^/]+\.jpg)$" REQUESTED_IMAGE_BASENAME=$1
SetEnvIf Request_URI "([^/]+\.png)$" REQUESTED_IMAGE_BASENAME=$1
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=\"%{REQUESTED_IMAGE_BASENAME}e\"" env=REQUESTED_IMAGE_BASENAME
```

Test Request:

```
HEAD /test/Water%20lilies.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
```

Test Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 23 Jul 2011 09:03:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32)
Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Aug 2001 14:00:00 GMT
ETag: "26000000017df3-14752-38c32e813d800"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 83794
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Water lilies.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

#### HTML5 Solution

You can [use the HTML5 `download` attribute on anchors](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#downloading-resources):

```html
<p>Example 1<br>
   <a href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png" download>Download this image</a></p>

<p>Example 2<br>
   <a href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png" download="alternate-filename.png"><img
       src="http://dummyimage.com/150x100/000/fff.png"></a></p>
```

Comment: The HTML 5 solution is simply amazing

Comment: The download attribute is not widely supported. You should probably not use it unless you plan on implementing a fallback for unsupported browsers. http://caniuse.com/download

Comment: Not now but in the next few years.

Comment: @LucasEduardo +1!! Especially if it is for personal use: No need to create any fallback for other unsupported browser. :)

Comment: as of 2015 only safari and IE doesn't support the  [download attribute.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp)

Comment: as of 2016 safari still doesn't support it. I don't know about IE, but who cares about IE...

Answer (score 15):

I have come up with pure JavaScript way to force download of image, with the following restrictions:

1. Using HTML5 so not working at all in IE browsers before IE9.
2. In IE (even 9) limited to very  small images, due to URL length limit.
3. The image name (when saved to machine) can't be determined in the code, in Chrome it will be just "download" without extension and in Firefox it will be what looks like jibberish string with ".part" extension - either way, user will have to rename the file to make it usable.
4. Can only download images in the same domain - same origin policy.

The above restrictions (especially the third) more or less renders this useless but still, the "core" idea **is** working and hopefully at some point in the future it will be possible to determine file name then it will become much more useful.

Here is the code:

```
function DownloadImage(imageURL) {
    var oImage = document.getElementById(imageURL);
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    if (typeof canvas.getContext == "undefined" || !canvas.getContext) {
        alert("browser does not support this action, sorry");
        return false;
    }

    try {
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var width = oImage.width;
        var height = oImage.height;
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        canvas.style.width = width + "px";
        canvas.style.height = height + "px";
        context.drawImage(oImage, 0, 0, width, height);
        var rawImageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png;base64");
        rawImageData = rawImageData.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
        document.location.href = rawImageData;
        document.body.removeChild(canvas);
    }
    catch (err) {
        document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        alert("Sorry, can't download");
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you can see, the trick is drawing the image into `canvas` object, get the raw binary data of the image then force download by using `image/octet-stream` mime type and changing the browser location.

Usage sample follows as well.

HTML:

```
<image id="myimage" src="Penguins.jpg" />
<button type="btnDownload" rel="myimage">Download</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var arrButtons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrButtons.length; i++) {
        var oButton = arrButtons[i];
        var sRelatedImage = oButton.getAttribute("rel");
        if (sRelatedImage && sRelatedImage.length > 0) {
            oButton.onclick = function() {
                HandleRelatedImage(this, sRelatedImage);
            }
        }
    }
};

function HandleRelatedImage(oButton, sRelatedImage) {
    var oImage = document.getElementById(sRelatedImage);
    if (!oImage) {
        alert("related image '" + sRelatedImage + "' does not exist");
        return false;
    }

    return DownloadImage(sRelatedImage);
}
```

This allows to "attach" download button to every existing image by assigning the `rel` attribute of the button to the image ID - the code will do the rest and attach the actual click events.

Due to the same origin policy can't post live example at jsFiddle - they're using "sandbox" domain to execute the scripts.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple solution that uses the HTML5 'download' attribute:

```js
document.getElementById('download').click();
```

```html
<a id="download" href="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0jH18Lft7ypSmRjdWg1c082Y2M" download hidden></a>
```

If it can find the picture it will download a cat picture.

Comment: I tested it with Firefix Developer Edition v43, Firefox v39, Microsost Edge, Internet Explorer v11 the image is displayed in the page, and no download  dialog appear

Comment: check this http://caniuse.com/#feat=download, please note that altough it's said that it should work with FF 39 but I tested this with image and it's displayed in the browser

Comment: One simple solution for all your download issues! Programmers hate him!

Comment: download attribut is not supported by safari

Answer (score -1):

This is totally possible. Just encode the image as Base64 then do a `window.open` with a `data:image/jpg,Base64,...`-style url.

Comment: This make me open image on new tab.