# How can we save HTML form data into xml format using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Here is a smiple html form,I want to get the data from it and convert into xml or get the data in xml format?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
<body>
   <form action="" method="post">
        <p>
           <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">

            <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">

        <button id="submitButton">submit</button>

    </body>
</form>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output HTML form data to a XML file using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383236/how-to-output-html-form-data-to-a-xml-file-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pure javascript solution for downloading any content you can use the following function:

```
function downloadData(contentType,data,filename){

   var link=document.createElement("A");
   link.setAttribute("href",encodeURI("data:"+contentType+","+data));
   link.setAttribute("style","display:none");
   link.setAttribute("download",filename);
   document.body.appendChild(link); //needed for firefox
   link.click();
   setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.removeChild(link); //only to remove the temporal link
   },1000);
}
```

Where contentType

For creating XML data from a form you can use :

```
function fromToXml(form){
    var xmldata=['<?xml version="1.0"?>'];
      xmldata.push("<form>");
    var inputs=form.elements;
    for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
        var el=document.createElement("ELEMENT");
      if (inputs[i].name){
        el.setAttribute("name",inputs[i].name);
        el.setAttribute("value",inputs[i].value);
        xmldata.push(el.outerHTML);
      }

    }
    xmldata.push("</form>");
    return xmldata.join("\n");
}
```

And then, try to modify the format as you expected.

See an example in https://jsfiddle.net/jmusfs9v/3/

If you are intenerested in generating a well-formed XML output from javascript you can follow the article: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/h/2127

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
function getXml(){
    var elements = document.forms.myForm.elements;
    var xmlTemplate = '<?xml version="1.0"?> <formData>';
    for(var i =0; i< elements.length; i++){
        var element = elements[i];
        if(element.tagName=="INPUT"){
            xmlTemplate = xmlTemplate + '<'+element.name+'>' + element.value+'</'+element.name+'>';
        }


    }
    xmlTemplate = xmlTemplate +'</formData>';
   return xmlTemplate;
}

getXml();
```