# Call a click on a newly added dom element

Tags: click, coffeescript, jquery

Im trying to call a click on this newly created anchor:

```
$('.file-status').html("Finished downloading <a class='download' download href='#{fileEntry.toURL()}'>#{name}</a>")
$('.download').click()
```

But the click event is not called. Not sure why this is?

Im trying to force a download, not open the link in the browser. Like Dropbox does

**EDIT**

Here is the code, so its more clear:

```
fileEntry.createWriter ((fileWriter) ->
    fileWriter.onwriteend = (e) ->
        $('.file-status').html("Finished downloading <a class='download' download href='#{fileEntry.toURL()}'>#{name}</a>")
        $('.download').trigger('click');
    fileWriter.onerror = (e) ->
        console.log "Write failed: " + e.toString()
    fileWriter.write blob

), errorHandler
```

**UPDATE:**

So after understanding from the answers below that this is not really possible, except if the server sends the data to me with the header Content-disposition: attachment. But this seems to me like a realy bad solutions to pure HTML5 JS apps, that might be offline.

So I found this, that handles this super awesomely! It works great. Here is the link:

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Hope this helps someone that wants to do the same as I am sure there are many!

Comment: What are you doing with click like this?

Comment: The user clicks on a link to download a file form the API, once the file is downloaded with the FILE API it creates this link. I want to start the download dialog for the user (as he clicked to download the file). It seems dumb to have the user click download, then once the file is downloaed click download file agian..

Comment: check my answer below i think it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the click event to the anchor tag and call click event.

```
$(".download").bind("click", function (e) {
            var $a = $(this);

                    window.location = $a.attr("href");

            });

 $(".download").click();
```

Comment: I have tried binding the click event to the element, it still does not call the click

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to simulate a user click ? If that's the case, this is how you do it:

```
$('.file-status').html("Finished downloading <a class='download' download href='#{fileEntry.toURL()}'>#{name}</a>");

// simulate/trigger a click
$('.download').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the trigger event but still the click is not called.

Answer (score 1):

You have not passed a event to the anchor, try this: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gnumA/

```
$('.file-status').html("Finished downloading 
                        <a class='download' onclick='alert(123);' href='#'>#{name}</a>")
$('.download').click();
```

### update:

```
$('.download').click(function () {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
}).click();
```

Comment: Ok, this works. But in my example I have the attribute download set so that once clicked, the file download dialog starts. So how would this work then

Comment: Still, it opens the file in the browser if its a image or pdf etc

Answer (score 1):

Show user the downloading has been finished and then redirect to downloading after 1 sec.

```
$('.file-status').html("Finished downloading <a class='download' download href='#{fileEntry.toURL()}'>#{name}</a>");

setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.href = $('.download').attr('href');  
},1000);
```

Comment: If the file is an image, the image will just be opened in the browser. I want to force a download

Comment: Most probably you need a server side language to force download. Javascript wont be help you in this regard. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796974/force-download-an-image-using-javascript)

Comment: But I mean the download attribute in the tag will force the download if the user actually clicks on the link.

Comment: You can only simulate the `onclick` event of `anchor`. Not the navigation click. `$('.download').trigger('click')` will only call the javascript function associated with `$('.download')` but wont navigate for you.

Comment: So this is not possible? So this "force download" must actually come from the API?

Comment: Wait, here is an actual way to use the html5 API to do it: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Comment: There's one more html5 way in the link I provided in my first comment above. But you need to consider browser support for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this pluggin [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

```
$('.download').livequery(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

Comment: I think your missing the point here. I want to programaticly click the link. The user can click it, thats not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is tagged with CoffeeScript here is a CoffeeScript valid answer (although still using jQuery).

```
itemId = $('.modal__product-info').attr('data-item-id')
$('#size-' + itemId).click()
```