# Onclick Image Download Link

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an Onclick image download link, when a user clicks on the link/button he should get an option to download

here is my code below

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="download" onClick="window.location.href='http://myimagelink.com'"   >
</form>
```

Why it is not working?

Comment: You dont need a form, just a anchor tag and use the image source for the src attribute..

Comment: Please write which file you want to give download like. pdf,png.jpeg,doc ..etc.

Comment: Please see this should answer your query - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796974/force-download-an-image-using-javascript

Comment: who ever has given negative rep ,,, it would be great if you comment why negative rep ...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this worked well for me ..

`<a href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png"
    download>Download this image</a>`

Answer (score 1):

That code won't work because you have added an `s` to the end of `window`.

You should be using a regular `<a href="">` for this though.

To trigger a download instead of causing the image to be rendered in the browser window, you need to use [the `Content-Disposition` HTTP header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) to mark it as an attachment.

e.g. with Apache configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.jpeg$">
        Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

There is no sensible way to use JavaScript for this (although, I imagine you could use XMLHttpRequest to download the image, generate a `data:` scheme URI from that, and then set `location.href` to that URI while lying about the content type).