# How to download video from website using an iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad

I would like to have a website with videos where the users can access this site through iOS 9+ using iPad.

The code below :

```
<a  href="myvids.mp4" download="mytextdocument">here video</a>
<a  href="img.jpeg" download="mytextdocument">here img </a>
```

Work well in Google Chrome App  using a Macbook but not in Safari as specified in the HTML5 documentation of the download attribute.

When I use the iPad using Google Chrome App, it doesn't work either, no popup to save the file. I need to long press on the image and wait to see a message that asks me to save the image file in the Gallery.

And this only work with the image, for the video I am not able to download it on the iPad even with long Press. Moreover the long press is not very user-friendly.

So my question is how to download some videos from my website using iPad, am I missing something ?

Comment: For starter you never should double same attribute in one element, also what "mytextdocument" is supposed to mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578473/how-to-make-safari-and-ie-to-download-images-instead-new-page

Comment: @Andrey Sorry my mistake same result without

Comment: @ Divyesh Savaliya thanks i already see the link doesn't work but my main goal is not to make the href work on safari but on iPad, at least Google Chrome because it seems difficult to make it work on Safari

Comment: @Andrey mytextdocument is the name attribute of the file when the download is forced.