# html - click a link to download image in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

Are there anyway to download an image by click to a link in safari.
I tried:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" download="w3schools_green.jpg">download image</a>
```

It worked in chrome but not in safari. Instead of download this image, safari open this link in a tab. and I've found out that "download" attribute is not supported in safari.

so, how could i force download it, without reload page, or open another tab.

I'm using java-spring-tomcat 7 to dev.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578473/how-to-make-safari-and-ie-to-download-images-instead-new-page

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. but I'm using Tomcat 7 not  Apache server.