# Download images using java script

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I am developing a cross platform app , where in I want to download few images from my back end using Java Script.

I see with HTML5 you can use "download" property of anchor  tag , but unfortunately it works only for Chrome and no other browser.

I have also tried some of the traditional ways like:-

http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2012/01/how-to-download-data-as-a-file-from-javascript.html

but that did not work. Can someone tell me an alternative that is not browser dependent.

I have also tried somethings like "modernizr" and "html5Shiv" but to no effect.

Comment: do you mean the onDownload event rather than *"download" property"*?

Comment: I want something like download property, which works fine for chrome but not for others.

Comment: can you use php readfile?

Comment: If your images are CORS enabled you may be able to use https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: No I am developing cross platform app , it has to be java script or html only.

Comment: do you know anything of blob?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796974/force-download-an-image-using-javascript
it is working for me

Comment: also check the 2nd most upvoted answer, within the thread mentioned by Dharmendra, using `canvas` http://stackoverflow.com/a/9158343/2835455

Comment: and a related article, http://greenethumb.com/article/1429/user-friendly-image-saving-from-the-canvas/