# trigger an automatic download from javascript doesn't work on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used the download attribute of a link to download a file. However, when I trigger the click event from another method, it doesn't download the file. Why is that so? I have checked that the click event is being triggered. Here's my test on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6Fkb5/1/

```
<a href="#" download="https://www.dropbox.com/s/shd31hvnsn0fd0v/Getting%20Started.pdf" id="testdownload">Test Download</a>

var count=0;
$('#testdownload').on('click', function(){
    count++;
    $('#log').append('<li>Click triggered ' + count + ' times</li>');
});


$('#testdownload').trigger('click');
```

Comment: @rakhi4110 is it when you run it or when the link is clicked?

Comment: I think you misuse the `download` attribute. It is to specify a different filename for the download link specified in the `href` attribute. It won't solve your problem, but maybe you should fix it nonetheless.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796974/force-download-an-image-using-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('#testdownload').get(0).click();
```

Edit: Just to clarify this will trigger a native click event instead of jQuery's.

Comment: Not really. It just doesn't want you to open a PDF in a fiddle frame. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/6Fkb5/10/

Comment: Sorry didn't try it in IE, but works fine in Chrome, so not sure why it got downvoted.

Comment: get(0) returns the domelement, which is what you would get if you would do document.getElementById('testdownload'). A jQuery selector wraps this domelement in its own object with its own methods.

Answer (score 1):

Will not work....

even if you delay it and wait for DOM ready:

```
var count=0;

$(function(){
  $('#testdownload').click(function(){
     count++;
     $('#log').append('<li>Click triggered ' + count + ' times</li>');  
  });

setTimeout(function(){ $('#testdownload').trigger('click'); },3000);

});
```

The reason is **SECURITY** protocols... browsers will not allow scripts to trigger a download request only by user click.

**EDIT:**

actually CHROME will support `$('#testdownload').get(0).click();` but IE will block your script.

The correct way to trigger a download (will work in most browsers except IE) is to use an `iframe`:

```
<iframe width="1px" height="1px" frameborder="0" src="{File location}"></iframe>
```

Comment: How do those other pages work, which do start downloads after a couple of seconds? And why does Ruben's answer work? Apparently this answer is wrong.

Comment: Server side deals with it, forcing the download response.

Comment: IE blocks it in the fiddle, because it tries to open it in a frame. Also, it tries to open the PDF rather than download it. It does work, though, if you add `target="_blank"`. No security issues, just IE being a bit quirky and trying to open the file. http://jsfiddle.net/6Fkb5/10/