# Force file download once a site is visited

Tags: html, web-services, file, web, download

I have a simple site example.com and an external file link. I want this scenario to be implemented:
Once a user visits example.com, a file from an external link is **automatically** downloaded.
Mind that I don't want a user to click some link, but just an immediate file download once the site is visited. Thus `<a href="link/to/file" download>Download</a>` is not what I need.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: window.open("link/to/file");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22125501/trigger-an-automatic-download-from-javascript-doesnt-work-on-page-load

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply create a link and click on it via js:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = "link/to/file";
  a.download = true;
  a.click();
};
</script>
```

Comment: you rock thanks - i have had such a hard time trying to actually get the answer I was looking for - kept getting other results

Comment: You can edit the suggested name to save the file as once it downloads by setting a.download = "filename";