# Trigger download immediately after document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to download a file immediately after a page has been loaded by triggering an a link.

```
...
<a id="download" href="/some/link/to/download.pdf"></a>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#download').trigger("click");
  });

</script>
```

But this isn't working for some reason. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067284/force-file-download-once-a-site-is-visited

Comment: Wow this actually works. Thnx

Comment: @patrickb write the answer for future users :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically create and click a link when the page loads - simply add this to the page markup:

```html
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "/some/link/to/download.pdf";
    a.download = true;
    a.click();
  };
</script>
```