# Trying to download all of the images on the website using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, download

I need some help with this script that I'm trying to make that downloads all of the images on a webpage. It downloads the first image just fine, then when Google Chrome tries to download the rest of them, it says "No File". Some help would be greatly appreciated. I run this code by pasting it into the javascript console. Thanks!

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var srcList = [];
var i = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    if(images.length > i){
        srcList.push(images[i].src);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.id=i;
        link.download = srcList;
        link.href = srcList;
        link.click();
        i++;
    }
},1500);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You’re using an entire array as the src attribute. try:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var srcList = [];
var i = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    if(images.length > i){
        srcList.push(images[i].src);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.id=i;
        link.download = images[i].src;
        link.href = images[i].src;
        link.click();
        i++;
    }
},1500);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this simpliest solution:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var i = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    if(images.length > i){
        window.open(images[i].src,'_blank');
        i++;
    }
},1000);
```

If you still have problem with downloading, you can try with [iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery).
or harder solution with [mod_headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796974/force-download-an-image-using-javascript) method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let webphotos = document.images;
Array.from(webphotos).forEach((extractedimages) => {
  console.log(extractedimages);
});
```

first of all this code extracts all the images form the website as u can see further u can do any custom operation on them according to your needs