# How to download an image in the current page without opening a new tab or changing the current window and such with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For example in this page : https://www.monstermmorpg.com/

I want to download this image into my given target folder

[image]

The url of the image is

```
https://static.monstermmorpg.com/images/HowToPlayTheGame/Main-Game-Screen.webp
```

So what kind of function i can use in console window of the chrome that would download this image when this page is open without opening any new window tab, or change current window and such

I mean console window of the chrome here

[image]

Simply without affecting currently opened window, without changing anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a base64 image to user's disk using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951326/how-to-save-a-base64-image-to-users-disk-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to download it without opening another window or adding things to the page, as far as I know. You would need to create some kind of link and then emulate a click, but for that you would need to add things to the current page (or create a new page with the link). Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You could emulate a click with JavaScript (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088897/trying-to-download-all-of-the-images-on-the-website-using-javascript) for example), but it would just open the image in the same tab.

Comment: I interpreted OP's requirements of not "changing the current window" to mean not adding anything or altering the dom, but to be honest I'm not exactly sure what they meant.

Comment: They later clarified: "Simply without affecting currently opened window", so I assumed they want it downloaded to the device storage

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work for your usecase. There is a `download` attribute available for `<a>`-tags. As far as i can tell it is meant to specify a name for the file downloaded.

So its meant to be used something like this

```html
<a 
  href="https://example.com/some-file-with-an-ugly-name/as9872uj21a8d792uads32.pdf" 
  download="report.pdf"
>
  Download report
</a>
```

But it seems that some browser will also treat links with the download attribute as download-links instead of actual links so you may be able to fix this by just putting the download attribute on the `<a>`-tag like:

```html
<a href="<some-url>" download>Download image</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends... what user gesture would be suitable to initiate such an image download?

I’ll use the right-click for this example...

```
function DownloadImage(Src){

let A=document.createElement('A'); 

A.target='_blank'; A.href=Src; 

A.download='someimage'; A.click();

}
```

In your HTML you need to add a **oncontextmenu** parameter to kick-start the function upon a user right-clicking on the image like this...

```
<img src="https://static.monstermmorpg.com/images/HowToPlayTheGame/Main-Game-Screen.webp" oncontextmenu="DownloadImage(this.src);" width="500" height="600">
```

PS: Greetings from Cyprus neighbor :)

Btw, seeing that you’re an expert in C/C++ I need some help too so I’d be happy to help in all things web if you can return the favor in C.  Write to me at support@theclassictools.com