# Download Image From Web Server On Button Click Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i download an image when the user presses a button on the web page.
I don't want to use `<a href download="file">` as it doesn't work on some devices. How can i do this using JavaScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force Download an Image Using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796974/force-download-an-image-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `download` attr to `<a></a>` link, or by event of other element:

```
$('button.download', modal).on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var url = ""; // Some URL.
  var fileName = "image.jpeg"; // Some File name

  var a = $('<a href="' + url + '"></a>')
    .attr('download', fileName)
    .appendTo('body');

  a.click(function () {
    a[0].click();
    $(this).remove();
  });

  a.trigger('click');
});
```

[EDIT]
In case of you don't want to use it, you `<a></a>` link need to have these headers in the server response of the file to download:

`Content-Type: application/force-download`

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.jpeg"`

`Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`